# Is there a way to include a php file that contains a variable?

Tags: php

I'm trying to include a php file that contains my HTML code, and inside this file I want to echo some variables. Let me show you my code:

This is the function I'm calling on the client by ajax, to get the HTML result:

```
    public function generateHtmlModal($orderId){
        $r = $this->getOrderData($orderId);
        $html = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/../view/modal-order.php");
        $html2 = "<h3>Order nº $r[order_id]</h3>";
        return $html;
    }
```

Note that I create $html2 to test and return instead of $html. That works nice, it prints the HTML with the order id. But I wanted to use HTML markup in a separate file, and load it into my PHP function. This is an example of the .PHP file with HTML markup that I want to include:

```
<!-- FILE MODAL-ORDER.PHP--> 
<div id="orderModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-body row">
                    <h3>Pedido nº <?php $r['id_pedido']?></h3>...
```

So, basically I expected PHP to just wrap the file inside the string variable $html, and interpret : $r['id_pedido'] as my $r variable from the function. I've tried some different options like including php starting tag, but no success.

Is this possible in this situation?

Comment: You should look into MVC frameworks like Codeigniter or study up on  TWIG templating.

Comment: You actually need to return the RESULT of the server PARSING/EVALUATING the modal-order.php file, not the file itself. The client can't run that PHP file directly. There is not directly a way to do what you are wanting. You need something to GENERATE the HTML you want to return.

Comment: `"Is there a way to include a php file that contains a variable?`" Yes, with `include` but not with whatever this is you're doing.

Comment: I expected php to wrap the whole content of the file into a string variable, so the client can read it (because it is pure html content afterwards). I could wrap my html code on a php string, but then I would have no support from IDE to edit my HTML content. I expected the file_get_contents to extract the content and wrap it in the variable. I don't know how to parse and evaluate the html content the way you suggest. :/

Comment: @developerwjk, if I use include, I would load HTML content inside my PHP function, wouldn't I?

Comment: It would probably make the function print the HTML rather than return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`:

```
<?php

public function generateHtmlModal($orderId)
{   
    ob_start();

    $r = $this->getOrderData($orderId);
    include(__DIR__ . "/../view/modal-order.php");
    $html = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $html;
}

?>
```